# task(function) not working(while using asyncio)

Tags: python, async-await, bots, python-asyncio

This is a program made as a game bot for performing simple tasks:

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import asyncio
import time
import random

a=random.randint(1,2)          
def grind():
    while True:
        pydirectinput.keyDown('left')
        time.sleep(a)
        pydirectinput.keyDown('right')
        pydirectinput.keyUp('left')
        time.sleep(a)
        pydirectinput.keyUp('right')
async def hunt():
    begin = time.time()
    pydirectinput.keyUp('left')
    pydirectinput.keyUp('right')
    time.sleep(3)
    pydirectinput.keyDown('1')
    pydirectinput.keyUp('1')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pydirectinput.keyDown('1')
    pydirectinput.keyUp('1')
    time.sleep(3)
    end=time.time()
    eltime=end-begin
    eltime=int(eltime)


async def main():        
    grind()
    while grind():
        if pyautogui.pixel(941,664)[0] == 205:
            task = asyncio.create_task(hunt())
            await asyncio.sleep(eltime)

asyncio.run(main())
```

In this program, I'm trying to run `grind()` and while `grind()` is running, when the `if` condition is satisfied, the function `hunt()` must take place while `grind()` is temporarily paused. `grind()` must resume as soon as `hunt()` is finished. However when I'm executing this program, `hunt()` doesnt work.

Comment: Could you specify "hunt() doesnt work"? What do you expect to happen? Do you get errors?

Comment: From your description of what you want to do, asyncio seems to be the wrong tool.  You say that grind() must be suspended while hunt() runs, and must resume as soon as hunt() returns.  That is exactly how _synchronous_ programming works.  You appear to have no use for asyncio.  Also your hunt() function does not contain any await expressions, so it will never multitask with other functions.